# How to fix ' Window TargetType does not match type of element WindowInstance' error?

Tags: c#, wpf

I designed a custom control library in WPF, every restyled controls nested in a resource dictionary and all resource dictionaries merged in System.Window.xaml. when i use my package from nuget to test, all control works fine but when i set style for main window to Style={DynamicResource MainWindowStyle} following design time error occurred:

'window' targettype does not match type of element 'windowinstance'

I have seen all the same problems on the Internet, but none of them have come up with a good solution.

my project source code:
https://github.com/mohsenmou/ui-wpf

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You question should contain the relevant code in a [mcve] rather than just linking to a repository. Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Also, you can just ignore the error; it is only caused by a bug the the XAML designer and doesn't actually prevent your program from building or running correctly.